# Manually set an IPv6 address via the GUI

Tags: configuration, ipv6

[Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS]

I am trying to manually assign an IPv6 addr via the GUI, but whatever I seem to enter for the Prefix, it says it is invalid. Here's an example:

[image: IPv6 Config screen]

I've also tried the following for the prefixes:

```
26B3:6040:A50:3F1::
26B3:6040:A50:3F1::0
26B3:6040:A50:3F1::/64
26B3:6040:A50:3F1::0/64
26B3:6040:A50:3F1
```

But get the same results. What is the correct formatting here?

Comment: I'm thinking you want "64"... I'm wondering how you even got those colons in there? I am no IPV6 master, but from what I understood at one time, a 64 prefix represents the first 64 bits of your IP address... so there would be no need to write it out again as the prefix in that box, just "64".

Comment: @WU-TANG that works - thanks! If you would like to create an answer, I will accept it.

Comment: your welcome... feel free to write it up and accept your own answer...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add 64 in Prefix.
Thanks to @WU-TANG's comment.

Following are the settings which work for me.
I have just copy pasted your Address for the sake of a screenshot.

[image: IPv6 Manual Settings]